# Does Bowser Jr. have a mom, and if so, who is she?

Tags: super-mario-brothers

Bowser Jr. is son of the King Koopa himself. I am unsure if this means biological son or otherwise, but the resemblance is uncanny. Bowser also seems to be protective and emotional when dealing with Jr. as seen in the DS games, so that leads me to believe the connection is deep.

How much do we know about Jr.'s background? Does he have a mother? Is he really Bowser's son? Did he ever go by Prince Koopa? These, I must know.

[image: Bowser Jr]

Comment: [Super Mario Sunshine spoilers](https://youtu.be/3amuWV3BXts?t=427). Make what you want of the awkward pause.

Comment: @OrangeDog Huge development! Could you add that as an answer?

Comment: You'll feel cheated, but his mother is Princess Peach.

Comment: Maybe Bowser’s species can self-impregnate like the Komodo Dragon. Not trying to be weird, it’s literally a fact. Some lizard/reptile species can self-produce. Bowser also seems to be quite powerful with Dark Magic so maybe he used that to create Jr.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Who better to ask than Super Mario creator [Shigeru Miyamoto?](https://youtu.be/uu2DnTd3dEo?t=41)

> **Q. Do you know who Bowser Jr's mother is?**
>
> **A.** *Points to himself*

Well, that can't be a canon answer...

In 2012 (by way of declaring that the Koopalings had been retconned into *not* being Bowser's kids), Miyamoto explained: [Bowser's only child is Bowser Jr., and we do not know who the mother is.](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/features/archive/2012/09/24/miyamoto-tezuka-interview.aspx) No further details have been revealed since.

Comment: HI, not everyone can view video links (plus they have a tendency of going dead). It's always better to include a transcript.

Comment: That must have been a weird pregnancy.

Answer (score 5):

Do you guys remember a stork carried Mario and Luigi to their parents in *Yoshi's Island*? That means in the Mario Universe Bowser doesn't need a wife to have Bowser Jr. All the children are carried by storks to their parents. so since Bowser Jr was just carried by a stork, Bowser Jr doesn't have a mother and Bowser was the only parent Bowser Jr had.

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but the stork is a metaphor for your parents getting busy.

Comment: That would explain Peach's [confusion](https://youtu.be/WKBNrfdQFaI?t=587) about the whole thing... (because, @Valorum, if it were really a metaphor, you'd think she'd have a clearer answer than "I'm your mama?").

Comment: The stork is not just a metaphor in the Marioverse.  It is a pretty important plot point in Yoshi's Island.